# How to do Prana Pratishtha of Idols of Ganpati, Shiva, Vishnu and Durga?

Tags: idols, pranapratishtha

To be specific I am asking about the procedure for prana pratishtha for Shri Mahaganapti, Lord MahaVishnu, Lord Shiva (shiva linga) and Godess Durga). Please answer mentioning vedic mantras and vedic methods to be opted before worshipping the concerned idol.

Comment: Shiva Purana has details about what all to do for Pran Pratishtha of Lord Shiva idol or a Shivalinga. I think Vishnu and Devi Bhagwatam should also contain similar things for Lord Vishnu and Goddess Durga's idols.

Comment: I need ganapati methods also

Comment: We have 2 puranas for Lord Ganesha, ie Ganesha Purana and Mudgal Purana, so relevant information must be in either of these. However, these 2 puranas are not part of the major puranas or sub puranas and are said to be written very lately around 1500 A.D. I think, so can't comment on whether these are authentic or not.

Comment: Is this in a temple or at home for a specific vrata? Or is it at home for nitya puja?

Comment: @moonstar2001 Home for ganesha chaturthi it is for special occasion